# How to use sudoers for python's script

Tags: python, sudo

I had a script (named script) in bash, and I wanted to allow an user (named "userScript") to run it as root without giving any password.

So, I edited the file /etc/sudoers and added 2 lines at the end :

```
Cmnd_Alias SCRIPT=/home/userScript/Desktop/script

userScript ALL:NOPASSWD: SCRIPT
```

(The script in the desktop is a symbolic link to prevent any modification)

It worked perfectly well. After some days, my script was too big, so I rewrote it in python, with multiples files, classes...

So, I changed nothing except the symbolic link's target, but now when I try to run the script, the terminal ask for a password, and give me an error (sorry if it's not exactly the good message, my Ubuntu isn't in English)

> Sorry, user userScript isn't allowed to execute "/usr/bin/python script" as root on name_of_my_computer

I run the script like this as user "userScript" :

```
sudo python script
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing `sudo /home/script/Desktop/script.sh`?

Comment: Ho, I never try to run a python's script by this way ! I suppose it's possible due to the first line #!/usr/bin/python. I can't try it now, I'll come back after trying the solution later. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that the command you try to run with `sudo` is  `python`; the script is first argument to `python`. Instead , your script should has executable permissions, and you're supposed to run it as `sudo script_name`.

Second, when you do `python script_name` , it won't necessarily look for your script, wherever it's stored. You either would have to give full path, or again, have the script itself live in one of directories listed in `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your sudoers file seems OK.
I did add a shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

and ran the script as

```
sudo script
```